# Graficar una tabla con muchas columnas en R

Tags: r, rstudio

como puedo graficar una funcion que he hecho en R? Se utilizar algunas graficas, pero esta en particular no encuentro como la puedo graficar ya que tiene 309 obs y 73 variables, esta es mi función:

```
porcentaje.preguntas <- df %>%
  group_by(Localidad) %>%
  select(Localidad, starts_with("X")) %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ scales::percent(mean(.x))))
```

Lo cual me arroja un porcentaje y me da esto como resultado:

```
Localidad  X2.1  X2.2  X2.3  X2.4  X2.5  X2.6  X2.7  X2.8  X2.9  X2.1.1 X2.11 X2.12 X3.1  X3.2  X5.1  X5.2  X5.3 
   <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 0001CIUDA~ 100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%   100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100% 
 2 01001AGUA~ 100%  99%   99%   100%  100%  98%   100%  100%  100%  100%   100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100% 
 3 01003CALV~ 100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%   100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100% 
 4 01005JESÚ~ 100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%   100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100% 
 5 01006PABE~ 100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  89%   100%  100%  100%  100%   100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100% 
 6 01007RINC~ 100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%   100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100% 
 7 01011SAN ~ 100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%   100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  100% 
 8 02001ENSE~ 100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  96%   100%  100%  100%  100%   100%  100%  100%  100%  99%   97%   100% 
 9 02002MEXI~ 100%  100%  100%  100%  100%  99%   100%  100%  100%  100%   100%  100%  100%  99%   99%   97%   100% 
10 02003TECA~ 100%  96%   96%   100%  100%  78%   100%  96%   100%  100%   100%  100%  100%  96%   96%   100%  100%
```

Como puedo graficar todo esto? Muchisimas gracias por contestar.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. La pregunta incluye código y un ejemplo de los datos y eso ayuda. Sin embargo podrías mejorarla y aumentar las posibilidades de obtener una buena respuesta indicando 1) que es lo que quieres mostrar en tu gráfico y 2) ofreciendo un ejemplo completamente reproducible, incluyendo acceso a tus datos. Les veo cara de datos del INEGI, así que seguramente serán públicos. Estrictamente puedes graficarlo de muchas maneras (puntos, barras, líneas, áreas, etc), pero no todas serán útiles para lo que quieras mostrar con tu gráfico.

Comment: Por lo que veo me parece que lo que tienes son múltiples medidas para cada localidad (posiblemente una o más variables medidas en distintos años). En ese caso podrías ubicar en el eje x a los años (o lo que sea que haga que se repitan las medidas), usar línea cuya altura se controla en el eje y y usar colores para distinguir las localidades y paneles para cada variable. Eso sería bastante fácil de hacer con la librería `ggplot2`, quizás lo más difícil sea generar la estructura de datos adecuada, por eso ayudaría un ejemplo concreto de los datos.

Comment: @mpaladino Gracias por responder, Lo que quiero mostrar en mi grafico es simplemente algo que pueda ser entendible para alguien que lo vea, Esto es una tabla con el porcentaje de las preguntas mas respondidas en el dataframe. Te comparto la liga de los datos: http://datos.imss.gob.mx/dataset/participacion-social-enguarderias/resource/f30ff883-2895-494a-8c12-ef256392b805

Comment: Perdon, no se por que se puso la liga mal pero es esta : http://datos.imss.gob.mx/sites/default/files/Resultados-MPSG-Open-Data-oct10-feb20.csv

Comment: Es bastante difícil lo que creo que buscas porque estarías graficando 21939 puntos de datos válidos, 22248 contando los `NA`. Me parece que es demasiada información para un gráfico. Además casi todos los valores que tienes son 100%: hay poca variación. Se me ocurren algunas alternativas: 1) agregar o separar en un nivel más alto (Delegación IMSS en lugar de localidad), 2) ajustar algún modelo de reducción de la dimensionalidad y graficar el resultado del modelo, no los datos crudos 3) centrarte en los casos en los que hay porcentajes bajos que podrían ser los interesantes.

Comment: Es que justamente es un trabajo de la universidad, y me pide sacar el porcentaje de cada Pregunta contestada por Localidad, por eso es que son muchisimos datos, De primaria instancia tambien se me ocurre graficar con un grafico de dispersion pero como la mayoria de los datos es el 100% pues no tendria chiste. @mpaladino

Comment: Lo más difícil de hacer un gráfico es saber qué es lo que queremos mostrar en el gráfico. Dicho de otro modo, saber  a qué pregunta responde ese gráfico. Sabiendo eso se pueden tomar decisiones sobre qué datos excluir, en qué nivel agregar, que modelo podríamos usar para reducir dimensiones. Entiendo que a veces por requisitos laborales/escolares hay que hacer un gráfico porque hay que hacerlo. Me ha pasado. Los resultados no suelen ser buenos.

Comment: Te entiendo. Si tienes que "cumplir" y entregar un gráfico puedes usar `  df %>% select(localidad, starts_with("x")) %>%
  group_by(localidad) %>% 
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~mean(.x))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = x2.1:x14.2, names_to = "pregunta") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=localidad, color = pregunta, y = value)) + 
  geom_point()` Es ilegible porque se superponen las etiquetas y la escala de color es imposible de interpretar, pero bueno...

Comment: @mpaladino En un momento lo pruebo, podrias ayudarme poniendolo como respuesta ? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3):

Va una respuesta que hace un gráfico de esos datos. No creo que sea una buena visualización, es mala en muchos sentidos. Pero cumple con el objetivo de hacer un gráfico.

```
df %>% 
  select(localidad, starts_with("x")) %>% 
  group_by(localidad) %>%                                #Hasta aquí es igual a lo que tenías, quizás cambien los nombres porque normalicé a minúsculas.
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~mean(.x))) %>%    #Quito el percent porque va a convertir a los números en caracteres y para el gráfico necesiton que sean numeric
  pivot_longer(cols = x2.1:x14.2, names_to = "pregunta") %>%  #Pivoteo los datos, para ggplot necesito que tengan formato largo
    ggplot(aes(x=localidad, color = pregunta, y = value)) + 
    geom_point()                                              #Uso puntos, ya de por sí está muy cargado como para poner barras.
```

¿Qué está mal en el gráfico? Al menos tres cosas:

1. Las etiquetas se superponen. Hay 300 valores discretos en el eje x, es prácticamente imposible que sean legibles.
2. La escala de colores es imposible de rastrear. Hay 72 colores distintos, al ojo humano se le complica mucho distinguirlos.
3. Hay poca variabilidad en los datos. Casi todos tiene el mismo valor (1 / 100%). Aportan poco información en este caso.

Answer (score 3):

La gráfica dependerá de lo que quieras mostrar, pero se me ocurre que por los datos, un mapa de calor podría venirte bien.

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Localidad) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = Localidad  , fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile(colour="gray80", size=0.2) +
  geom_text(aes(label=value)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "YlGnBu", direction = -1, na.value = "white")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sí, es mucho mejor que un gráfico de puntos o barras. El color sirve mucho porque lo homogéneo de los 100 dirige la atención a los casos inusuales. Quizás se podría ordenar el eje y o x para concentrar las filas/columnas con mayor proporción de respuestas con porcentajes bajos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por comentar @patriciomoracho, me parece una buena opcion para graficar ya que tengo muchos datos y es buena opcion. Tratando de correr tu codigo que me proporcionaste me da este error: ```Error in continuous_scale(aesthetics, "distiller", gradient_n_pal(brewer_pal(type,  : 
  unused argument (pallete = "YlGnBu")``` como lo puedo resolver?